# Yodlee UI closing issue

Tags: vuejs2, yodlee, nuxtjs2

I'm using the yodlee for some developing purposes for my ongoing project with nuxtjs 2.I cannot close the rendered Yodlee UI by clicking the close button in top of the yodlee page. However, the back button is working as expected after selecting a bank.

[image]
The initial page

[image]
After selecting a bank and its working(the go back which is in the top of the left side)

Even no console errors and I just tried with the class of the a tag related to the button below
[image]

```js
mounted() {
  let fastLinkCloseBtn = document.getElementsByClassName(
    'icon-link close-icon'
  )
  if (fastLinkCloseBtn) {
    console.log('working')
    fastLinkCloseBtn.onClick = window.fastlink.close()
  } else {
    console.log('not working')
  }
},
```

Comment: What do you see in your devtools? Any errors? Maybe a CSS layer on top of it? Hard to tell without having the actual code or a [repro].

Comment: @kissu no console errors

Comment: `mounted` is run only once, when the component is mounted. Are you sure it fits within your use case? Also, do you **need** to access the DOM here? Why don't you use an `@click` on the icon?

Comment: yodlee UI loads from a URL to iFrame here. So I cannot use @click event there